# How can I share album between 2 users

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, nosql

I am creating an application using Android/Java, and I am stuck at a place where I need to make connection between 2 users.

Doctor and patient it is 1-to-1 relation 1 doctor can only have 1 patient and vice versa.

User to Album(Gallery) it is 1 to many relation 1 user can create as many albums as he needs..

Now my query is how can i make patient album to be visible with doctors page and doctor's album should be visible on patients page.

My Firebase looks like this now,

[image]

Now album made by doctor are for patient as doctor is helping patient maintaining his part.

I need to know how can I make both of them view all albums created by them.

NOTE: the albums will be visible to these 2 users and not to new users, new users will be sharing with their pair mate.

Comment: Add new field in your collection when a user logged in your app like isPatient =true...you can display your items based on field

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.